# Lock model for reading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

In an `ActiveRecord` transaction, I need some way to lock the record/table for reading, so the user was not able to select from this table, while the transaction being executed.

Basically, I need something like this

```
System.transaction do
  s = System.first
  # Something to lock the table or selected record for reading
  s.update_attributes(some_params)
end
```

Does anyone have an idea on how to do that?

Comment: Why do you need to lock reads? Maybe there's a better way. Postgres for example has read locks for entire tables, but not for rows.

Comment: I store a state variable for executing a process. And I need to lock this record while changing the variable, to avoid collisions.

Although, I'm open for better suggestions if you can think of better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are looking for [Pessimistic Locking](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Locking/Pessimistic.html). You can use the `lock` method like a scope. Additionally, you should use the bang-version `update_attributes!` in order to raise an exception when things go wrong.

```
System.transaction do
  s = System.lock.first
  s.update_attributes!(some_params)
end
```

Comment: Does this thing work with MySql? I was still able to read the record after locking it.

Comment: Again, why lock reads? Lock the resource to be changed for update, not some state variable for read!